# How does one require a password to be changed when setting an Active Directory password programmatically?

Tags: c#, active-directory, passwords

I am using the following code to reset a user's Active Directory password.

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext( ContextType.Domain ))
{
  using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity( context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName ))
  {
      user.SetPassword( "newpassword" );
  }
}
```

But I need to be able to require the user to change the password after the first time they log in.  I can't find a method or setting or property that does the job, however.  It is evident that this can be done, I just can't find out how!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to expire the newly created password right away - try this:

```
using (var context = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain))
using (var user = UserPrincipal.FindByIdentity(context, IdentityType.SamAccountName, userName))
{
    user.SetPassword("newpassword");
    user.ExpirePasswordNow();
}
```

See the [MSDN docs on ExpirePasswordNow](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library%20/system.directoryservices.accountmanagement.authenticableprincipal.expirepasswordnow.aspx) for more details

Comment: @rae1n: if you have a system that generates system passwords, you want the user to be able to login once with that system-generated password, but then require him to change it right away. Makes perfect sense to me.

Comment: *net user name password*
***DO NOT USE IT!*** It doesn’t change the password, it resets it. When you reset the password this way, all things encrypted with user password are no longer accessible (unless you have the certificate backed up and want to go with manual decryption process). This includes EFS, user specific encrypted app configs, passwords, some Outlook settings etc. https://blog.adamfurmanek.pl/2020/12/12/changing-user-password-from-command-line-in-windows/